# Using iCheck callbacks and jquery to remove items from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, icheck

I have a dynamic list that I am creating when a user clicks on certain checkboxes.  I am using iCheck, which has certain event handlers built in.  What I would like to have, is the ability to remove one of the "rows" of this list, when a user unchecks the specific checkbox.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var callbacks_list = $('.callbacks ul');
            $('.facebook-friends-larger input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
              callbacks_list.prepend('<li><span>#' + this.id + '</span> is ' + event.type.replace('if', '').toLowerCase() + '</li>');
            });

            $('.facebook-friends-larger input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {


            });

          });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="facebook-friends-larger">

            <?php $offset_two=0; ?>     
            @foreach ($friends as $friend)
            <li>
            <div class="facebook_friend_large">
                <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" name="friend[]" id="{{$friend}}" value="{{$friend}}">
                <label for="{{$friend}}" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <span class="icon"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}/picture" alt="" height="50" width="50"></a></span>
                    <span class="icon_text_large"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{{ $friend }}"><?php echo $friend_names[$offset_two]; ?></a></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            </li>
            <?php $offset_two++; ?>                 
            @endforeach

    </ul>


<div class="callbacks">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

My question is how do I remove the rows with the Unchecked event handler?  I know it is something along the lines of:

```
$('#'this.id).remove();
```

id's are unique.

But this throws an error.  How would I accomplish this?  Thank you.

Comment: did you try `$(this).remove();` ?

Comment: yes, this is not working, and it doesn't allow me to uncheck the box when I have it there.

Comment: Please post your PHP code as well

Answer (score 1):

You are using following code to add a new `li`

```
.prepend('<li><span>#' + this.id + '</span> is ' + event.type.replace('if', '').toLowerCase() + '</li>');
```

within this event handler

```
$('.facebook-friends-larger input').on('ifChecked', function(event){ //... });
```

So, logically, you can use following code to remove an `li` (IMO), depending on `prepend`

```
$('.facebook-friends-larger input').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('span#'+ this.id).closest('li').remove();
});
```

**Update :** Change your `prepend` to

```
.prepend('<li><span id="#'+this.id+'">#' + this.id + '</span> is ' + event.type.replace('if', '').toLowerCase() + '</li>');
```

And then replace the `remove` line in the function with this

```
$('.callbacks ul').find('span#'+ this.id).closest('li').remove();
```

Also, make sure, all `id`s are unique, two elements can't have same `id`.

Comment: @user1072337, Post your `html`.

Comment: HTML added to the original question

Comment: This still does not remove the rows when I "uncheck"

Comment: yes, the prepend line is working fine, and it displays the row like it should.

Comment: hmm, I made the change that you recommended in your answer and it is still not working.

Comment: Any more ideas?  This is puzzling.

Comment: I tried making a fiddle using the iCheck plugin, but I cannot get it to work with iCheck...http://jsfiddle.net/ECF7A/1/.  Here is iCheck: http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/

Comment: It's not working because `iCheck` didn't work (), check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ECF7A/3/) and try to make `iCheck` working.

Comment: hmm, I can't seem to get iCheck working...I uploaded the URI path, but still nothing..

Comment: Could you try?  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.  But the iCheck works fine in my dev environment.